# Multiline mode in Perl and Ruby different: Ruby is wrong?

Tags: regex, ruby, perl

Let us look at Perl code and result:

```
$s = "a\nb\nc\n";
$s =~ s/^b/X/;
print $s;

a
b
c

$s = "a\nb\nc\n";
$s =~ s/^b/X/m;
print $s;

a
X
c
```

I think Perl is right, ^ matches the position after new line in the middle only when multiline is enabled.

Let us look at Ruby:

```
$s = "a\nb\nc\n"
print $s.sub(/^b/,'X')

a
X
c

$s = "a\nb\nc\n"
print $s.sub(/^b/m,'X')

a
X
c
```

The ^ matches the position after newline in the middle of text regardless if it is in multiline mode or not.

For the life of me, I cannot find Ruby documentation which defines what the multiline option will do, where is it?

Also Ruby has no Single line mode (s)?

```
undefined group option: /(?s)^b/
```

`/^b./s` will parse but it does not behave like Perl (. matches new line).

PS: I tested using Perl 5 and Ruby 3.0.

Comment: Unfortunately, large parts of Ruby have no independent written formal specification. The specification for large parts of Ruby is "whatever YARV does". Since I assume you are using YARV here (to my knowledge, no other Ruby implementation implements Ruby 3.0 at the moment), whatever result you are seeing is *by definition* correct.

Comment: In Ruby (more generally, in Oniguruma) multiline mode (`/m`) is what is called *DOTALL* mode in many other languages: it causes the dot `.` to match line terminators as well as all other characters. In many other languages `/m` causes the anchors `^` and `$` to match the start and ends of a line, rather than the start and end of the string. Ruby doesn't need that because `^` and `$` are line anchors and `\A` and `\z` are string anchors.

Comment: Both are right, because they're different languages with different regex implementations with different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby and Perl's `/m` work differently.

---

Ruby's `/m` changes the behavior of only `.`. It is equivalent to Perl's `/s`.

- Ruby `/m`: Treat a newline as a character matched by .
- Perl `/s`: Treat the string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

Perl's `/m` changes the behavior of `^` and `$`.

- Perl `/m`: Treat the string being matched against as multiple lines. That is, change "^" and "$" from matching the start of the string's first line and the end of its last line to matching the start and end of each line within the string.

`^` and `$` always work this way in Ruby. Ruby effectively always has Perl's `/m`.

Ruby and Perl both share `\A`, `\z`, and `\Z` to match at the beginning of the string, end of the string, or just before the final newline.

Which is correct? Neither, they do their own thing. Perl's default behavior for `^` and `$` is the same as [POSIX regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_09), but they are incompatible in other ways. Python uses the equivalent of Perl's multi and single-line modes ([MULTILINE and DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags)). Ruby simplifies the behavior of `^` and `$` and makes regexes more explicit.

See Also

- [Ruby Regexp Anchors](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors)
- [Ruby Regexp Options](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options)
- [Perl Regexp Metacharacters](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Metacharacters)
- [Perl Regexp Modifiers Overview](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Overview)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The subtle difference does cause confusion, why cannot we agree on each other?

Comment: @puravidaso These languages are 20 to 30 years old, they were making it up as they went along. "Standard" [POSIX Regexes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) available at the time are pretty weak sauce by today's standards. Folks *mostly* copied Perl, and this was eventually "standardized" as [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), but any differences are frozen for backwards compatibility. Programmers were more monolingual then and standardization between languages was not a big concern, just looting the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> I think Perl is right, ^ matches the position after new line in the middle only when multiline is enabled.

Yes, that is correct. According to [`man perlre`, section *Metacharacters*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Metacharacters), the `^` anchor means:

> Match the beginning of the string (or line, if /m is used)

> Let us look at Ruby:
> […]
> The ^ matches the position after newline in the middle of text regardless if it is in multiline mode or not.

Also correct. According to [the documentation of the `Regexp` class, section *Anchors*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors):

> `^` - Matches beginning of line

> For the life of me, I cannot find Ruby documentation which defines what the multiline option will do, where is it?

It is in [the documentation of the `Regexp` class, section *Options*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options):

> `/pat/m` - Treat a newline as a character matched by `.`

> Also Ruby has no Single line mode (s)?

In Ruby, you can deactivate a mode by prepending it with a dash `-`. So, if you are currently in multiline mode, and want to go back to singleline, you don't need a separate mode for that. You can just turn off multiline mode again using `-m`.

Comment: It sounds from what you said that Ruby's `/m` causes `.` to match LF? If so Ruby's `/m` is equivalent to Perl's `/s`. (Not the absence of `/m` as you say)